# how to change email format from html to text in magento for admin?

Tags: magento

in magento on order confirmation email is sent to admin in HTML format,
but i want to change it to plain text format so how and from where i can change that format only for admin, customer should get email in HTMl format as it is.

Can anyone please give me solution for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create custom email template from `Transactions emails` and text type set as plain. Note down that template Id. and use in below file.

At `\app\code\local\Mage\Sales\Model\Order.php` `sendNewOrderEmail()` load manually template is and sent variables to that and send email.

Comment: @user1537552 until you have to update magento and can't work out why your system mysteriously fails.

Answer (score 2):

For future readers, **do not edit core files** as others suggest. You can achieve this in config alone with a *tiny* custom module.

I have AheadWorks' blog module installed, you may not, or you may have other modules that need their email format overridden. So, adjust accordingly.

Create `app/etc/modules/YourNameSpace_EmailFormat.xml` and add to `<depends>`, so your config is loaded last:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <YourNameSpace_EmailFormat>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Contacts/>
                <AW_Blog/>
            </depends>
        </YourNameSpace_EmailFormat>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Create `app/code/local/YourNameSpace/EmailFormat/etc/config.xml`, adding elements for all the templates you wish to override:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <YourNameSpace_EmailFormat>
            <version>1</version>
        </YourNameSpace_EmailFormat>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <template>
            <email>
                <customer_create_account_email_template>
                    <type>text</type>
                </customer_create_account_email_template>
            </email>
        </template>
    </global>
</config>
```

That's it. I needed the reverse, so I had `<type>` set to `html`. This goes very well with [Yireo's Email Override module](https://github.com/yireo/Yireo_EmailOverride) so you can easily customise your templates. If converting plain text emails to HTML, be sure to change template tags like `{{var foo.bar}}` to `{{htmlescape var=$foo.bar}}` to prevent malicious code injections.

Answer (score 0):

you have to override and extend the `Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template` model to achieve this and  set the correct header from there and you can't separate those by user and you ahve to build your own logic for that

Comment: please tell me in detail.. I am new to all this..please :(

Comment: exact which file and function i need to change?

Comment: you need to learn how to search :) open this file up and see where the mail object get's initiated

Comment: when order is placed that time in which function i need to put custom email template. so how i do that. change email template is too long an d tough to solve