# Change plain text email into HTML email

Tags: html, email, magento

This is in Magento 1.9.x.

I just edited the contents of a transaction email, added some HTML code into it, but the email is still rendering as plain text.

How do I make that email into a HTML email?

Here is how it looks in Magento:

[image]

The email contains HTML tags, but it's template type is Text.

I cannot find anywhere to either (a) change this template type to HTML OR (b) create a new HTML template.

This is the email content:

```
<body>
<img alt="Flamefast" src="http://www.flamefast-gas-safety.co.uk/skin/frontend/default/gas-safety/images/logo.png" />
<h1>Web Enquiry Form</h1>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<tr>
<td>Name:</td><td>{{var data.name}}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Email:</td><td>{{var data.email}}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Telephone:</td><td>{{var data.telephone}}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Company:</td><td>{{var data.company}}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Interested in:</td><td>{{var data.interest}}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Quote Required:</td><td>{{var data.request_quote}}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Info Required:</td><td>{{var data.request_info}}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Call-back Required:</td><td>{{var data.request_callback}}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Message:</td><td>{{var data.comment}}</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
```

And this is what it looks like in my email client. None of the HTML is being rendered. My problem here is I cant find *anything* in Magento's Admin Panel that could create a HTML email or change this to a HTML email.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/72994/magento-contact-us-custom-transactional-email-customer-received-plain-html-code

Comment: this is not a duplicate - I followed the instructions in this. All my HTML is being rendered as plain text. I cant see any options to change this. Perhaps I am stuck on this part: "You need tag to tell browser this is html."

Comment: have a look at this answer from another post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11839766/how-to-change-email-format-from-html-to-text-in-magento-for-admin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your template type is text beacuse you are using contact email as in your screen shot , it is by default in text format, you have to create an email template as below
    1.click on add new template button .
    2. Do not load contact email template.
    3. Load any one else if you want otherwise.
    4. write template name, subject and paste your html in content area and save 
    thanks!